# C# Multidimensionarrays difference between setting a Value

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, setvalue

is there any difference between those two pieces of code in their outcome?

```
Array[d1, d2, d3] = value;
```

and

```
Array.SetValue(value, d1, d2, d3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is [*type-safe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) second one is *not*.

Consider this:

```
int[,,] array = new int[3, 3, 3];
array[0, 0, 0] = "foo"; // oops!

array.SetValue("foo",0,0,0); // OK for now, but at runtime...
```

Other than that there is no *real difference*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in their outcome, but as Selman22 pointed out one method is type-safe while the other is not. Seeing how SetValue supports variable parameter count however both have their reasons to exist.

Typesafety will ensure however that you don't insert values which will blow up at runtime.